# problem in creating free space for root, swap and home

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I'm trying to install ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows 7. I'm done with the partition part where, I've created a free space of 50GB for root, swap and home directories. I'm using liveusb to install ubuntu. Everything went fine until they asked about the installation type, as I chose something else for installation type. But, the main problem is that I can't see the free space which I've allocated beforehand. I can see the following devices:
/dev/sda
/dev/sda1
/dev/sda2
/dev/sda3ntfs
/dev/dsa4ntfs
 What might be the problem?
Help me ASAP.

Comment: How does it describe "sda1" and "sda2"? Because "sda3ntfs" and "sda4ntfs" (not dsa4ntfs) look like Windows to me.

Comment: Can you elaborate it a little?

Comment: No. I can't read your screen.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into LiveCD and run Gparted. It gives you visual representation of partitions which is easier to understand for newbie. I guess installator had already prepared your free space for installation. You will just need to delete these extra partitions from Gparted.

Answer (score 0):

You have to judge by partition size. Map it with you Disk Manager in your Windows system, or try with the Disks or GParted utilities provided on your Ubuntu live CD (as [Barafu said](https://askubuntu.com/a/512826/22949)).

*Or* simply try [Wubi](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide).

#### How does it describe `sda1` and `sda2`?

While Windows names partitions with drive letters (such as `C:`, `D:`, `E:`), Unix-like operating systems, such as Ubuntu, use a different syntax.

Quoting from [Shadur](https://superuser.com/users/73044/shadur)'s [answer](https://superuser.com/a/558163/105707) to [What does /dev/sda for linux mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/558156/what-does-dev-sda-for-linux-mean) (on [Super User](https://superuser.com/)):

> - `/dev/` is the part in the unix directory tree that contains all "device" files -- unix traditionally treats just about everything you
>     can access as a file to read from or write to.
> - **sd** originally identified a SCSI device, but since the wildgrowth of USB (and other removable) data carriers it became a catch-all for
>     any block device (another unix term; in this context, anything capable
>     of carrying data) that wasn't already accessible via IDE. When SATA
>     came around, the developers figured it'd be much easier and much more
>     convenient for everyone to add it into the existing framework rather
>     than write a whole new framework.
> - The letter immediately after **sd** signifies the order in which it was first found -- a,b,c...z, Aa...Az... etc. (Not that there are many
>     situations in the real world where more than 26 discrete block devices
>     are on the same bus...)
> - Finally, the number after that signifies the partition on the device. Note that because of the rather haphazard way PCs handle
>     partitioning there are only four "primary" partitions, so the
>     numbering will be slightly off from the actual count. This isn't a
>     terrible problem as the main purpose for the naming scheme is to have
>     a unique and recognizable identifier for each partition found in this
>     manner...
>
> So `/dev/sda9` means the ninth partition on the first drive.